# How can I indicate a specific TextCtrl within a window frame and print to it, based on program result, on wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to print an info text to a `TextCtrl` widget specified by the program itself and don't know how. I only know how to do this 'manually' (let's say with a part of the program that do `self.text_ctrl_5.SetLabel("blah")` or `self.text_ctrl_27.SetLabel("blah")` respectively), but I have no idea how to instruct the program to do that by itself, I mean if condition A -> then print specifically to text_ctrl_5, if condition B -> then print specifically to text_ctrl_27.

For just 2-3 positions I can expand the line code (create one print instruction dedicated for each text_ctrl), but for 16 or 24 entries I am looking for some compact solution.

Suppose I have this two text positions to display, which are just part of a bigger window frame, how can I instruct the program to print on specific position ? Let's say if today is Monday then print "mon" on text_ctrl_1 and if Tuesday then print "tue" on text_ctrl_2 ? (days of week condition is just for example, not the actual need; also the label to print could be the same on different positions (or not))

```
self.text_ctrl_1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
self.text_ctrl_2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 16-24 text boxes on one screen, then it's probably time to rethink your user interface. Simple is almost always better. I don't understand why you couldn't just print your messages to one or two multiline text boxes. But regardless, I think the easiest way to do this sort of thing with a dictionary. Here's an example:

```
import random
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.text_ctrls = {}

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        for i in range(12):
            txt = wx.TextCtrl(self)
            self.text_ctrls[i] = txt
            sizer.Add(txt, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Update TextCtrls")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onButton(self, event):
        """"""
        ctrls = self.text_ctrls.keys()
        choices = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
        for i in range(3):
            ctrl = random.choice(ctrls)
            self.text_ctrls[ctrl].SetValue(random.choice(choices))


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test", size=(800,600))
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The basic idea is to create a series of text controls and add them to a dictionary. Then in the update button, we randomly choose a day of the week to apply to a randomly chosen text control.

Comment: "it's probably time to rethink your user interface" -> Not far from truth, only that for the moment I will stick with the version I built some time ago. I will consider that for a possible next project. The UI looks [like this](http://secarica.ro/misc/wxpyui_example.png) (seems in Firefox a http:/ / must be added manually in url bar) and requires a mix of dropdowns and color attributes for different "cells". I am trying to learn the possibilities (and potential limitations) of the wxPython UI, so any experiment is welcome. Will play with your solution, thank you.